# Find individual values from a "group by having" query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing approx 8,000 rows.

It has 15 columns in it and one of those is a "reference number".

My goal is to find all rows that match each other, and for the matching rows, find out what the reference number is.

The reference number is a bit random and doesn't really have a relationship to the rest of the data.

This is the SQL I have so far which gives me all the matching rows and count:

```
select 
count(*),
component,
privileges,
protocol,
authority,
score,
means,
difficulty,
hierarchy,
interaction,
scope,
conf,
integrity,
availability,
version
from 
data
group by
component,
privileges,
protocol,
authority,
score,
means,
difficulty,
hierarchy,
interaction,
scope,
conf,
integrity,
availability,
version
having count(*) >1
order by count(*) desc;
```

The row I have missed off the query, because I cannot get this to work as intended if I include it is `reference_number` I require the reference number for every row that comes through as a hit for this query. So, if the count(*) is 23 for one set of columns that matches the query, what is the reference number for all 23. That's my problem and I'm not sure if I can do that with SQL.

I can make new tables, or views, I felt like a subquery might help at first, e.g.

```
select reference_number from
    (select 
    count(*),
    component,
    privileges,
    protocol....
```

etc

But that fails with:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

Any help appreciated. (I am using Postgresql if that helps).

Comment: Consider this a subquery (or inline vie)view, i.e. put this in from clause. Then join that to the table again to get the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the string_agg() function.

The function signature is

> string_agg ( value text, delimiter text ) → text. Concatenates the
> non-null input values into a string. Each value after the first is
> preceded by the corresponding delimiter (if it's not null).

So in your original query, add a column with string_agg(reference_number, ','). This will give you a comma-separate list of reference numbers for each row.